# Generalized stokes theorem over the punctured disc

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, vector-analysis

I was reading Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds and when I reached his proof of Stokes' Theorem,
I noticed he states

> **Theorem:** If $\omega$ is $(K-1)$ form on an open set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and if
> $C$ is a K-chain then
> $$\int_{\partial C} \omega = \int_{C} d\omega$$

If we take the example of $\omega = Pdx + Qdy$ where $P_{Y}=Q_{x}$ then we get Greene's theorem. However, when looking at the classical example of
$$P=\frac{-y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}, Q=\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$ Greene's theorem does not hold meaning Stokes would not hold either. However, in looking through the proof of General Stokes, I could not see any reason for why this example fails the conditions needed for the theorem to hold. I can guess that maybe the reasons it does not hold is because Stokes needs $\omega$ to be exact, or perhaps the holes cause some issue with the boundary of $C$ but I have no real intuition over which of these, if any of these, are the problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is *the* example of a closed but not exact differential form. Keep reading whatever book you're reading and they'll talk about it.

Comment: What is your $2$-chain $C$ in what open set $A$?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Hi, yes I know that this example is closed but not exact. I was wondering where in the proof/conditions of Stokes would cause this example cause the theorem to fail.

Comment: Briefly: there is no single Stokes's Theorem. There are many variations each with different hypotheses and machinery. They all say basically the same thing, though: $\int_\partial = \int d$. In most formulations the punctured disc is not a valid domain because it doesn't have a good boundary. Indeed, you have to have some notion of what it would mean to integrate over the boundary of a punctured disc before you can say that Stokes's Theorem has failed in this case.

Comment: @TedShifrin I believe in context it is any open set that can contain a k-cube (I assume $k\leq n$) In this case I guess C can be the unit disc and A can be any open set that contains C.

Comment: $C$ cannot be the unit disk because $\omega$ is not defined on the unit disk.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins That makes some sense. Do you have any literature I can read as to why the punctured disc does not have a good boundary and why that causes most formulations of stokes to not work. Thank you!

Comment: Yes sorry I meant punctured disc, which I guess does not work based on what this theorem requires, I was just wondering where in the proof the need for the space to have no holes comes into play.

Comment: The boundary of the punctured disk is in some sense the perimeter plus the point you removed at the center. But those have different dimension. The perimeter is 1 dimensional and the point is 0 dimensional. We tend to only integrate over domains of fixed dimension. It's not clear what it should mean to integrate a 1-form over a point.

Comment: @ManseejKhatri The space absolutely can have holes. If instead you considered the 2-chain $\phi : [1, 2] \times [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\phi(r, \theta) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$, i.e. the annulus of inner radius 1 and outer radius 2, you would find that Stokes's Theorem holds. It's not about holes; it's about whether or not you can write down your space as a chain. There is no chain which represents the punctured disk. If you like, this "failure" of Stokes's Theorem is proof of that fact.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Hi that makes a lot of sense thank you for your explanations!

Comment: @CharlesHudgins That is not right. You can make the disk a (smooth) singular $2$-chain in such a way that its boundary is the boundary of the punctured disk, but then the important issue is that $\omega$ is certainly not smooth on the entire chain.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the correction. I'm not aware of this construction. Could you write down the 2-chain? The intuition I had in mind with my comment is that the punctured disk is not a manifold with boundary and so can't be written as a chain in any "natural" way, but clearly that isn't right.

Comment: @TedShifrin Forgive me if this is a silly question but why does $\omega$ need to be smooth. I thought it just had to have measure 0 set of discontinuities.

Comment: Absolutely not, Manseej. Nowhere in Spivak will you find such a thing. @Charles, we’re not talking about manifolds with boundary: we’re talking about chains. Think about the rectangle $[0,1]\times [0,2\pi]$ and map by polar coordinates to the plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I'm misunderstanding. Wouldn't that chain just be the disk, not the punctured disk?

Comment: Reread my original comment. Of course, the punctured disk is not a closed subspace. My point is that by thinking of manifolds, you’re misdirecting. Smoothness of the form is the crucial thing.

Comment: @TedShifrin Why does $\omega$ need to be smooth?

Comment: The standard Stokes’s Theorem requires $C^1$. You need to apply Fubini’s Theorem and the FTC.

Comment: @TedShifrin That makes sense thank you